# LMDE, Windows 7 Dualboot ond UEFI Laptop

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, linux-mint, uefi, grub2

I've bought an Asus laptop where was Windows 8 preinstalled. Then, I've dropped Windows 8 and installed Windows 7 on the whole HD instead. This drive has a 100 MB system-reserved boot partition.

Today, I've installed a second HD in the laptop and installed LMDE on it which has an 100 MB EFI partition, and an ext4 partition for the rest of the drive, where LMDE is actually installed, including GRUB2 in the /boot/ folder.

Using the tool grub-customizer, I've added  the following Windows 7 boot option to grub 2:

```
set root='(hd0,1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 5E5ABE565ABE2AA3
drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
chainloader +1
```

But when I try to boot from this entry, I get the following:

```
Error: No argument specified
Error: Unknown command "drivemap"
Error: Invalid EFI file path
```

Can someone help me fix those errors?

**Update**

As @Rod Smith suggested, I've ran the bootinfoscript and uploaded it here: http://pastebin.com/4QfHY1tW

Comment: Your Linux installation is in EFI mode, but the custom Windows GRUB option you've created is designed for a BIOS-mode GRUB and Windows. It's unclear from your description if Windows is installed in EFI mode or in BIOS mode, so it's impossible to say how you should proceed. I recommend you run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates to a pastebin site, and post back with the URL to your document.

Comment: @RodSmith I've uploaded the result and added the link to my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Boot Info Script normally produces much more output than that, but it's obvious that you do *not* have an EFI System Partition (ESP), contrary to what you believe. You've got the Master Boot Record (MBR) on both disks and Windows is installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. There's no evidence that GRUB is installed on the disk, although it could be that the Boot Info Script is omitting something. That would be consistent with your description that GRUB is launching and issuing error messages -- but it could also be that GRUB is starting up from a USB flash drive or the like.

Converting Windows to boot in EFI mode will be difficult, given what you've got now. Overall, I'd say that your best bet is to install a BIOS-mode version of GRUB and manage your dual-booting exclusively in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. This is probably most easily done with the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. Be sure you boot it in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, though. (Check for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`. If it's present, you've booted in EFI mode and you should *not* run Boot Repair like that.)